# How silent install .air file using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

Need me install .air app using PowerShell scrip. I write this in my command line `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Temp\UpgradeClientInstaller\setup.air" -ArgumentList "/S /v/qn"`, but this command don't install app.

Comment: What flags does it support? Use `--? setup.air` or `/? setup.air` in a PowerShell window.

Comment: PowerShell support / flags.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of distributing AIR packages, you need to use the "Adobe AIR Application Installer" and not the AIR file itself. I don't have a AIR package available so the code is not tested, but something like this could work:

```
$AIRInstaller = "${env:CommonProgramFiles(x86)}\Adobe Air\Versions\1.0\Adobe AIR Application Installer.exe"
$AIRFile = "C:\Temp\UpgradeClientInstaller\setup.air"
Start-Process -FilePath $AIRInstaller -ArgumentList "-silent -euleAccepted -programMenu -location $AIRFile"
```

See the [Adobe AIR Runtime Redistribution Instructions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/redist/WS485a42d56cd19641-70d979a8124ef20a34b-8000.html) for more command line options and exit codes.

Answer (score 0):

To complete Olaf Reitz nearly perfect answer (Indeed `-location` didn't work for me):

```
Start-Process -FilePath $AIRInstaller -ArgumentList "-silent -eulaAccepted -programMenu $AIRFile" -Wait
```